# Centering child div to parent div

Tags: html, css, centering, nested

This should work. I just want that the nested div is in the center of the parent div.
Is this at least the correct approach to center something, or am I way off the standards?
I'm just beginning to build my websites.

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:980px;
    height:900px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#logo {
    width:960px;
    height:305;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
}
```

and the markup

```
<body>
   <div id = "container">
        <div id = logo><img src="img/johndoe.jpg" width="960" height="305"/></div>
   </div><!-- end of container -->
</body>
```

Actually, the nested div is at the leftmost of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute;` for the logo.

Answer (score 1):

remove `possition:absolute;` from `.logo`

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:980px;
    height:900px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#logo {
    width:960px;
    height:305;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*position:absolute;*/
}
```

Comment: It works. But I am confused. If you have a parent element with a different state than static (like in my case), shouldn't you have a position that's relative to it, when creating child elements? This is what I'm reading: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out http://codepen.io/skeep/pen/nGupC

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    width:980px;
    height:900px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.logo {
    width:350px;
    height:150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```